# Identify the part where the video was viewed

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, django

I was creating an online movie portal in Django. If the user who is seeing the movie leaves the site, he is seeing the movie again from the beginning. I want to solve this problem and record the part of the video I saw in the base. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you are displaying the movie, and whether it supports any callbacks to let you know how far the user has watched in the movie. If there is such a callback, you can use that to record an entry in the database, in the user table keyed on the movie ID, indicating the number of seconds watched.

The movie component also needs to support starting playback from a certain location.

The solution will depend on the movie component you are using.